# unterminated string constant with if else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am coding a quiz and need to have it display a certain answer depending on the score.

I had this working when I just had the score being displayed, but now that I have added in the if else, it has stopped working and I am getting an unterminated string constant

```
$total_score = $first_question + $second_question + $third_question + $fourth_question + $fifth_question + $sixth_question + $seventh_question + $eighth_question + $ninth_question + $tenth_question + $eleventh_question + $twelfth_question + $thirteenth_question + $fourteenth_question + $fifthteenth_question + $sixteenth_question ;
});

$("#btn").click(function() {
   $('#reveal').html("<h3><strong>Total score</strong> " + $total_score +"</h3>"); 

if ($total_score >= 13) {
$('#answer').html("<h3><strong>13-16: Answer</strong></h3>"); 

} else if ($total_score >=9 && $total_score <= 12) {
$('#answer').html("<h3><strong>9-12: answer</strong></h3>"); 

} else if ($total_score >=5 && $total_score <= 8) {
$('#answer').html("<h3><strong>5-8: answer</strong></h3>"); 


 } else {
 $('#answer').html("<h3><strong> everything else</strong></h3>"); 
 }

});
```

Comment: Are there new lines beginning `</strong><` ? if so that's the problem, make sure that they are on the same line as the opening quote `"`.

Comment: Have you though about doing the `$total_score =` part in a loop?

Comment: I updated the code to move the <strong> lines into the correct place, but I am still getting an error on the second else if that I can't seem to get to work

Comment: You have an extra `});` in your paste ... aside from that what you have works; http://jsfiddle.net/hzqLM/ you will need to expand your example

Comment: All of this together helped fix the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the line breaks as @Spork noted, you need to remove the extraneous "})" after the $total_score calculation:

```
    $total_score = $first_question + $second_question + $third_question + $fourth_question + $fifth_question + $sixth_question + $seventh_question + $eighth_question + $ninth_question + $tenth_question + $eleventh_question + $twelfth_question + $thirteenth_question + $fourteenth_question + $fifthteenth_question + $sixteenth_question ;
    /* must remove the following:
    });
    */
    $("#btn").click(function() {
        $('#reveal').html("<h3><strong>Total score</strong> " + $total_score +"</h3>"); 

        if ($total_score >= 13) {
            $('#answer').html("<h3><strong>13-16: Answer </strong></h3>"); 

        } else if ($total_score >=9 && $total_score <= 12) {
            $('#answer').html("<h3><strong>9-12: answer </strong></h3>"); 

        } else if ($total_score >=5 && $total_score <= 8) {
            $('#answer').html("<h3><strong>5-8: answer </strong></h3>"); 
        } else {
            $('#answer').html("<h3><strong> everything else</strong></h3>"); 
        }

    });
```

Comment: I find using a JavaScript syntax editor/debugger (Eclipse,  VS 2012 Web Developer Express - both free) really helps to pinpoint errors like these.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript treats line ends roughly as semicolons (;), so you cannot have multi-line strings as you have in your script. Remove them, and it'll be okay.

Comment: You *can*, but I wouldn't suggest it. I think you put a backslash at the end of a line and it will allow you to continue your string on the next